# If $b-a>1$ then there is a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a<k<b$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, integers

Given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $b-a>1$, there is at least one $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a<k<b$.

**My attempt**:

Consider $E:=(a,b)\cap \mathbb{N}$. We need to show that $E$ is not empty. Set $b:=a+1+\varepsilon$. Then $(a,b)=(a, a+1+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. But $(a, a+1+\varepsilon)$ contains the elements $a, a+1, a+1+\varepsilon$, and $a<a+1<a+1+\varepsilon$. Set $k:=\min\{(a+1)\cap \mathbb{N}\ne \emptyset\}$. Thus $k$ exists.

I know this proof is lame, but I have no idea how else to develop this. Would appreciate some hints.

Comment: $E$ can certainly be empty: consider the case $a=-3,b=-1$.

Comment: By the archimeadean principal there is an integer $n$ such that $n \le a < n + 1$.  As $n \le a$ the $n + 1 \le a + 1$.  Now  $b - a > 1 \implies b >  a + 1 \ge n + 1 > a$.  $n + 1$ is an integer.

Comment: of course you might have to prove the archimedian principal.  Which is a result of the reals having a least upper bound property.  Let S be all integers $\le a$ then S is bounded above be $a$. so let $n = \sup S \le a$.  Proving $n$ is an integer is tedious but doable.  Then $n + 1$ is an integer and $n+1 > n$ so $n+1 \in S$ so $n + 1 > a$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: do you think my proof will become valid if I redefine $E:=(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @sequence: I’m afraid not. You seem to be assuming that $a$, and therefore $a+1$, is an integer; this need not be the case.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Why? I'm not assuming $a$ to be an integer. But I probably don't see why you think otherwise.

Comment: @sequence: Because with that assumption I can see why you might have thought that you had an argument, but without it I can’t: either you’re essentially assuming what you’re trying to prove, or what you’ve written makes no sense at all. (And the expression $\min\{(a+1)\cap\Bbb N\ne\varnothing\}$ makes no sense anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $E$ can certainly be empty: consider the case $a=-3,b=-1$. How your proof goes will depend on what you’re allowed to assume or have already proved. The hypothesis implies that $a<b$. Let $A=\{n\in\Bbb Z:b\le n\}$. If you are allowed to use the fact that every non-empty set of integers that is bounded below has a least element, let $m=\min A$, and use $m$ to find an integer between $a$ and $b$.

If not, you’ll have to work a bit harder. Let $A=\{n\in\Bbb N:|b|\le n\}$, and let $m=\min A$. You can use this $m$ to find an integer between $a$ and $b$, but you’ll need to consider two cases, one for $b\ge 0$ and one for $b<0$.

Comment: -3<-2<-1, so E is not empty.

Comment: @AnandJ: $E$ *is* empty: $-2\notin\Bbb N$.

Comment: $-2\notin \mathbb{N}$ it is not an issue the way problem is specified, though the proof presented by OP fails.

Comment: @AnandJ: And I was obviously talking about the argument presented by the OP.

Comment: ok my bad then.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a<b$
now $A=ceil(a)$, i.e. $A$ smallest integer s.t. $A>=a$.
Then $A>=a$ by definition of $A$. We have to prove that $A<b$.
Suppose not, then, $A>b$, then $A-a>A-b+1>1$.
That means $A>a+1$. So $A-1>a$, but $A-1$ is also integer contradicting the $A=ceil(a)$ assumption above.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your basic tools are.

The archimedian property states: For any real, $a$ there exist an integer $n$ such that $n \le a < n + 1$.  So if $b - a > 1$ then $b > a+1$ and we have:

$n \le a < n + 1 \le a + 1 < b$.  So $k = n+1$ is a integer that satisfies.

Of course we have to prove the archimedian property...

The reals have the least upper bound property.  Let $S = \{n \in \mathbb Z| n \le a\}$.  S is bounded above by $a$ so let $n = \sup S \le a$.  Let $1 > \epsilon > 0$ then $v - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound so there is an integer $n \le v \le a$.  $n + 1> v$ is an integer but $n +1 > v = \sup S$ so $n + 1 \not \in S$ so $n + 1 > a$.  So $n \le a < n+1 $.

Hmmm... I guess we need to prove $S$ isn't empty... sigh...

Comment: I dont know what archimedean property you are using but what my texts say dont require $n\le a$ at all, only an $n>a$. And its a strict inequality, what I have.

Comment: There are many renditions of it.  Your text has it in the basic form but it follows immediately that between any two reals there's a rational at that every real is between two integers uniquely determined. And what do you mean your text doesn't *require*? This is a concluding result-- not a conditional premise.

Answer (score 0):

As whole numbers are not upper bounded, let n be the smaller whole number greater than a. If n<b it is done.

So suppose n>b , then:

(1) n-1 > b-1

(2) and by hypothesis b-a > 1 , so b-1 > a

Therefore ( using (1) and (2)), n-1 > b-1 > a

So i found another whole number n-1 greater than a , which is absurd cause n was the minimum whole number greater than a , and n-1 < n

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).